# Calling a method while setting innerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling with calling a method while setting innerHTML. 
I apologize if there is a straightforward answer I have overlooked, but at the moment I am stuck.

Se the code below:

```
"<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry('" + element.id + "')'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>"
```

You can see that there's a mess regarding the quotes. 
Is there a third way to type quotes or something of the kind that can allow me to call "removeEntry(element.id)"? I need quotes around element.id in order to call removeEntry. Any suggestions on how to solve this in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

`"<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry('" + element.id + "')'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>"`

with

`"<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry(\"" + element.id + "\")'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>"`

In fact, the problem is with you current code, the `a` tag `onclick` property will be looking like `onclick='removeEntry('myId')'`

Note there's imbricated simple quotes, breaking your function call. Replace the `id` simple quotes by escaped double quotes , and it'll give you `onclick='removeEntry("myId")'` that is fine :)

**Edit** : Anyway, if you're targeting recent browser, you could try [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), that will give you the following line :

`` var html = `<a href="#" onclick="removeEntry('${element.id}')"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>`; ``

This helps to avoid struggling with your quotes. Note that the variable inclusion in the template literal looks like PHP do.

Comment: It works! Thank you for sparing me more headaches. Escaping quotes is new to me, but I'll definitely remember it from now on :)

Comment: @Tøffelen You're welcome! Check the edit, it might help you if you can use ES6 template literals :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'<a href="#" onclick="removeEntry(' + element.id + ')">
   <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
</a>'
```

This should work out. **You can encode double quotes in single quotes** and you want this whole expression as a string.so a string with variable can be written as
string1 = string2 + variable +string3;

Or for a multi lines string in JavaScript you can use back ticks.

```
`<a href="#" onclick="removeEntry(' + element.id + ')">
       <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
 </a>`
```

Comment: Please include some explanation as to why this might solve op's problem

Comment: Also remember the hapiness of defining [multiple-lines strings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/2435443) on JS.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
"<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry('" + element.id + "')'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>"
```

will create an element like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry('someId')'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>
```

Which is not correct. What you need to do is to either:

1. **Use the other quotes `"`** (but you have to escape them):

like this:

```
"<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry(\"" + element.id + "\")'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>"
```

to create an element like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry("someId")'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>
```

2. Or **Add a backslash `\` to the `'` quotes** (you have to escape the backslashes as well):

like this:

```
"<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry(\\'" + element.id + "\\')'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>"
```

to create an element like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='removeEntry(\'someId\')'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a>
```